# ADFS Authentication in flutter application

Tags: flutter, authentication, adfs, adal

I have a requirement to authenticate my flutter application from ADFS. I tried the ADAL package (https://pub.dev/documentation/flutteradal/latest/) but it doesn't seem to be fulfilling my needs. I don't have a lot of experience with server side programming or Microsoft services. Any help in making me understand how the ADFS authentication works would be life saving for me right now. I would really appreciate a step by step guide to ADFS authentication in flutter application.